# Laravel: Getting Route Parameters in Route::group() Closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an app running on Laravel 4.2, and I am trying to implement a somewhat complex routing mechanism. I have a route group set up using:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{wildcard}.example.com'], $closure);
```

I need to be able to check the $wildcard parameter *in the closure for the group* -- meaning before the request gets passed to the controller (I need to defined `Route::get()` and `Route::post()` depending on the subdomain).

An example of what I'd like to do is as follows:

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{wildcard}.example.com', function ($wildcard) {
        if ( $wildcard == 'subdomain1' ) {
            Route::get('route1', 'Subdomain1Controller@getRoute1');
            Route::get('route2', 'Subdomain1Controller@getRoute2');
        } else if ( $wildcard == 'subdomain2' ) {
            Route::get('route1', 'Subdomain2Controller@getRoute1');
            Route::get('route2', 'Subdomain2Controller@getRoute2');
        }
    }
);
```

Of course, the above does not work. The only parameter passed into a `Route::group()` closure is an instance of `Router`, not the parameters defined in the array. However, there *must* be a way to access those parameters -- I know for a fact that I've done it before, I just don't remember how (and can't find the solution anywhere online).

I know I can always use PHP's lower-level methods to retrieve the URL, `explode()` it, and check the subdomain that way. But I've done it before using Laravel's methods, and if possible, I'd prefer to do it that way (to keep things clean and consistent)

Does anyone else know the solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just can't do that. Route groups run before the request is dispatched.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done it in the past, unless I'm just going crazy. Actually, I vividly remember *doing it*, I just don't remember how. Either way, I decided not to worry about it and just hacked together a workaround using  `parse_url()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Route::input()` function:

```
 Route::group(['domain' => '{wildcard}.example.com', function ($wildcard) use ($wildcard) {
        if ( Route::input('wildcard') === 'subdomain1' ) {
            Route::get('route1', 'Subdomain1Controller@getRoute1');
            Route::get('route2', 'Subdomain1Controller@getRoute2');
        } else {
            Route::get('route1', 'Subdomain2Controller@getRoute1');
            Route::get('route2', 'Subdomain2Controller@getRoute2');
        }
    }
);
```

See "Accessing A Route Parameter Value" [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters).

Comment: I think this is almost right, but I'm getting the error `Call to a member function parameter() on null`. It looks like `Route::current()` is not set. I'm trying to debug it right now